# no output from unix shell script

Tags: bash, unix

I have the following shell script (named `test`):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "junk"
filename="junk"
echo $filename
filename=`ls -t|head -n1`
echo $filename
```

when I run this script there is no output to the terminal.
I am using red hat / putty.

What am I missing?

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? What is the output you *were* expecting? What's the purpose of this script?

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: I ran it on my system with Mac El Capitan and it works.

Comment: There is no much information in the question, but my guess is that you first echo line should have been:

echo "junk" > junk

Answer (score 7):

You're accidentally running the system command called `test`, which produces no output. You need to use `./test` instead to find the script in the current directory, whereas `test` will use the built-in shell command (and even if it didn't, it would find `/usr/bin/test` instead).

This is why you should avoid calling your test programs `test`. Try `try` instead.